# How to do multiple if statements sas EG

Tags: sas

I am new to sas EG so unsure how to do this:

I am trying to write a small bit of code within my proc sql that takes a column of phone numbers and creates a new flag column. I want the new column to produce a Y when the phone number is: not empty, 11 digits long, only digits and not equal to '11111111111' and a 'N' otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to this site (and SAS). I suggest you read the rules. When posting your question you should be as detailed as possible, share some of your data (or use SAS tables from sashelp library), and your attempted code. It makes other users job much easier if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data have;
    input phone_number :$20.;
    datalines;
123456789
11111111111
122355648978
12354879874
555566648+8
246k5654322
56485432135
asdfghjklop
;
run;
```

Syntax for if statements in proc sql is the same as in sql: you use case statement. If you have multiple conditions, you can add more when condition then result lines.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as 
        select phone_number, 
        case
            when phone_number ne '' and phone_number ne '11111111111' and length(phone_number)=11 and length(compress(phone_number, ,"kd"))=11 then 'P'
            else 'N'
        end as flag
            from have
    ;
quit;
```